# How to disable in-app browsers

Tags: applications

I am currently using Google Family Link for my child's Samsung Android to disable web browsing but they are still able to click links within certain apps and open in-app browsers. This is the case in Skype and just about any other app with links within it.

Is there a way to disable in-app browsing altogether?

Thanks for the help.

Comment: You can try disabling Android WebView and all the browsers that are installed in your device. It is unlikely those certain apps have built there own in-app browsers and so must be depending on external browsers with webview offering. To know how to disable an app, search `pm disable-user` term in our website.